# SSL/TSL Certificate for IP Address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have the following curl command to grant permission to user (local):

```
curl "https://10.10.135.35/9880/grant_permission?user=username&role=role" -k
```

I want to use fetch in js with same purpose. Something like:

```
const fetchAPIPro = (username, role) =>
    fetch(`https://10.10.135.35/9880/grant_permission?user=${username}&role=${role}`, {
      referrerPolicy: 'unsafe-url',
      credentials: 'omit',
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.blob();
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
      });
```

It returned `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`. I think this happened because of the SSL/TSL Certification that I created (self-signed). 
Is there anyway to bypass this in `fetch` or grant certification for the domain?

Comment: SSL certificates are not bound to an IP, but a domain.

Comment: @Keith SSL certificates from public CAs are bound to DNS addresses, but the SSL certificate itself can contain IP addresses: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160787/ip-address-in-subjectaltname

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `rejectUnauthorized: false` to your header

Answer (score 0):

if you are executing in the browser, that error is going to be thrown as browsers don't validate against self-signed certificate for cross origin domains. You can get a free valid certificate from letsencrypt

Comment: Let's encrypt using CertBot only allows domain SSL not IP Address SSL